# How did 'folding' semantically shift to mean 'repeat'?

Tags: etymology

[Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=replication) proclaims that

> *replicare* "to repeat, reply," literally "to fold back,"

originates

> from *re-* "back, again" (see [re-](https://www.etymonline.com/word/re-)) + *plicare* "to fold" (from PIE root [*plek-](https://www.etymonline.com/word/*plek-) "to plait")

What notions underlie folding and repeating?

p 1785 on [*Oxford Latin Dictionary* (2012 2 ed)](https://www.amazon.ca/Oxford-Latin-Dictionary-Dictionaries/dp/0199580316) doesn't expound the semantic shift. I marked the entry with a red line.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked what [Lewis and Short say on *replico*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=replico&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059)? The route from the basic meaning to II.B.2 gets some more perspective if you read the whole entry.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Thanks. I read the *OLD* (now quoted!), and not *Lewis and Short*, but now that I have, I'm still too stupid to connect the dots.

Comment: This isn’t really a question about Latin at all. Nevertheless, I would suggest concentrating on all the different kinds of plication (ex, in, con, re, ad, sub) simultaneously since they will give a better sense of parallel evolution.

Comment: @Cerberus. Certainly. Am I wrong to assume that *Oxford Latin Dict.* (last revised 2012) is better than *Lewis & Short* last revised in 1879?

Comment: @Greek-Area51Proposal: Oh! I am ashamed. I read it as *Oxford English Dictionary*, how stupid of me (the letters in the image were too small to read without opening it in a new tab). The Oxford Latin Dictionary is fine, of course! It is generally the better dictionary, although perhaps in this case Lewis & Short can be helpful, as they usually provide more possible translations of each sense of a word.

Comment: I don't see the link with "folding" in the title of the question. Could it be edited?

Answer (score 4):

*[Plico](http://archimedes.fas.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/dict?name=ls&lang=la&word=plico&filter=CUTF8)* means "to fold, roll, wind". *Re-* means "back, again", so *[replico](http://archimedes.fas.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/dict?name=ls&lang=la&word=replico&filter=CUTF8)* means "to fold back, roll back, rewind". A sense "to roll over" is not very different; this no doubt developed from "roll back".

As it often happens, that concept could be used figuratively: "to roll something over in the mind". As rolling or folding an object or substance, such as a scroll, a braid, a toga, involves spending some time touching it and being able to inspect it from multiple angles, the figurative sense flows into "reflect upon [an idea]". (Cf. *re-flecto* "to bend back, turn back".) *Re-* suggests going over it again, so the sense of repetition lies in that praefix. When you reflect upon an idea, you think about it again and again; it's not just one simple act of thinking. Perhaps *re-* had a double effect: perhaps the step from "reflect on" to "repeat (in the mind)" was owing to the subconscious' taking the sense of repetition from *re-* into account a second time. Or perhaps it makes sense as a reinterpretation without duplicity. At any rate, the sense of *repeat* developed post-classically, so after the other senses, according to Lewis & Short.

As to replying, that originates in late juridical Latin (Lewis & Short). A reply means saying something back to the original utterance, so I think it is logical for that sense to be expressed by *re-* as well. As to why folding (back) came to mean uttering (back), I imagine the figurative sense "to roll something over in the mind" was expanded to rolling something over in a conversation, inspecting it by talking about it.

The full entry on *replico* from Lewis & Short:

> **rĕ-plĭco**, āvi (e. g. Vulg. Gen. 4, 27; id. Jos.
>   8, 35 al.), ātum (collat. form, replictae tunicae, Stat. S. 4,
>   9, 29), 1, *v. a.*, *to fold* or *roll back*, *to bend* or *turn back*
>   (cf.: revolvo, reflecto).
>
> **I.**  Lit.: vel Euhemero replicato, vel Nicagorā, etc., unrolled, opened, Arn. 4, 147; cf. infra, II.: surculos in terram
>   dimittito replicatoque ad vitis caput, bend back, Cato, R. R. 41, 4;
>   so, labra, Quint. 11, 3, 81; cf.: replicatā cervice, Plin. 34,
>   8, 19,  80; and: margine intus replicato, id. 9, 33, 52,  102: ab omni
>   laevitate acies radios tuos replicat, casts back, reflects, Sen. Q. N.
>   1, 3, 7; cf.: quia radii solis replicantur, id. ib. 2, 10, 3: jocinera
>   replicata, folded inwards, Suet. Aug. 95.—
>
> **II.**  Trop., *to unfold*, *unroll*, *turn over; to bend* or *turn back; to open*: ut ne replices annalium memoriam, unfold, turn over,
>   Cic. Sull. 9, 27; so, memoriam temporum, id. Leg. 3, 14, 41: traductio
>   temporis nihil novi efficientis et primum quicque replicantis,
>   unrolling, unwinding, id. Div. 1, 56, 127: cujus acumen nimis tenue
>   retunditur et in se saepe replicatur, is bent back, Sen. Ben. 1, 4, 1:
>   vestigium suum, *to withdraw*, i. e. *to go back*, App. M. 4, p. 151,
>   15.—
>
> **B.**  In partic.
>
> **1.**  *To turn over and over in the mind*, *to think* or *reflect upon; to go over*, *repeat* (post-class.): haec identidem mecum, App.
>   M. 3, p. 129: titulos, singula, Prud. στεφ. 11, 3: necem, to tell
>   again, Amm. 30, 1, 3: vitam, Sid. Ep. 7, 9: lamentum, Vulg. 2 Par. 35,
>   25; id. Num. 27, 23: quorum (glirium) magnitudo saepius replicata
>   laudatur adsidue, Amm. 28, 4, 13: vultu adsimulato saepius replicando,
>   quod, etc., id. 14, 11, 11. —
>
> **2.**  In jurid. and late Lat., *to make a reply* or *replication*, Dig. 2, 14, 35 *fin.*; Greg. Mag. in Job, 16 *init.*

Comment: +1. Thanks. I hope you don't mind that I just narrowed this question to 'repeat', and asked anew for 'reply', so that each post is devoted to one semantic shift.