# How did 'folding' semantically shift to mean 'reply'?

Tags: etymology

I seek more details and other opinions than [Cerberus's answer that cited Lewis & Short](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/12668/37) on 
what notions underlie folding and replying.

> As to why folding (back) came to mean uttering (back), I imagine the figurative sense "to roll something over in the mind" was expanded to rolling something over in a conversation, inspecting it by talking about it.

How can 'roll over in mind' broaden to mean 'roll something over in a conversation' then to 'reply'? I've never heard of the VP 'roll something over in a conversation' in English; it doesn't feel intuitive.

[Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=replication) proclaims that

> *replicare* "to repeat, reply," literally "to fold back,"

originates

> from *re-* "back, again" (see [re-](https://www.etymonline.com/word/re-)) + *plicare* "to fold" (from PIE root [*plek-](https://www.etymonline.com/word/*plek-) "to plait")

p 1785 on [*Oxford Latin Dictionary* (2012 2 ed)](https://www.amazon.ca/Oxford-Latin-Dictionary-Dictionaries/dp/0199580316) doesn't expound the semantic shift. I marked the entry with a red line.

[image]

Comment: Opinion: My intuition tells me that *unroll*/*unwind* variant of the original meaning is probably a better candidate for the semantic shift you're looking for. When you *reply* you *unroll* your thought to your interlocutor...

Comment: Is this just a copy-paste of the previous question that got closed as duplicate?

Comment: @Draconis No. Previous question didn't have para 3.

Answer (score 5):

It seems to me you could ask the same question about *return* and *retort*. Apparently the idea that an argument or question is like a ray or missile directed at you, and you *turn* it around or *bend* or *fold* its trajectory when you make a reply, underlies these words. (Note how, for example, the English word *retort* simultaneously refers to a reply in an argument and a chemical flask with a bent neck.)

In the Oxford Latin Dictionary entry, you already see uses like this:

- *radii soli replicantur* (sunrays are reflected [= bent back] by the earth: Seneca, Naturalis Quaestiones, 2.10.3)
- *vestigium suum replicat* (he turned back, returned: Apuleius, Metamorphoses 4.19)

It seems natural to me to extend this to a conversation between people, where utterings, or thoughts and ideas, are sent back and forth.

Please note that the meaning *reply* in general (not just in the courtroom) may be a Middle Latin development, and the OLD, which explicitly excludes Middle Latin, would in that case not be the right resource to consult.

Answer (score 2):

A modern equivalent of the same semantic shift would be monitor speakers which are often called 'fold-back' speakers, because they 'fold back' the sound to the musicians on stage, this is almost like an echo, which could be viewed as a "reply" to the person making the noise.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the shift from "folding" to "returning" Sp. Llegar, wiktionary has some interesting comments:  "The semantic shift over time from "to fold" is also found in some other Romance cognates, and may be linked to the idea of folding sails when arriving at a port, especially in Iberian Romance where naval tradition was strong. Compare Portuguese chegar; however cf. also Romanian pleca (“to leave”), with the opposite meaning, possibly because there the word was associated with folding up tents and leaving."